# Why does getFragmentManager() return null the 2nd time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform

I have an android application with a submit button.  Pressing submit saves form data into the parse cloud, then replacing the current fragment with a different one:

```
    submitAnswerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String answer = answerET.getText().toString();
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            Answer newAnswer = new Answer(answer, qid, currentUser);
            newAnswer.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I noticed I can crash the app if I quickly hit the submit button twice.  After the crash I see the form data in my parse table twice.

1. What is the best practice for preventing double submissions?  I was thinking of not persisting if the time between 2 submit clicks is less than 3 seconds:

   ```
   DateTime lastTimestamp = null;
   public void onClick(View v) {
       DateTime currentTimestamp = DateTime.now();
       if(lastTimestamp == null)
           lastTimestamp = currentTimestamp;

       DateTime betweenClicks = currentTimestamp - lastTimestamp;
       lastTimestamp = currentTimestamp;
       // if a click happened within 3 seconds of the last one, show error and dont save again
       if(0 < betweenClicks <= 3 seconds)
       // show error dialog here
       return;

       String answer = answerET.getText().toString();
       // rest of the code(save into parse)
   ```
2. Not that it matters for my solution, but the debugger showed that the crash was due to getFragmentManager() returning null the second time, why is it null the second time?  If I submit normally, then submit another answer the same way it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it's getActivity() that is returning null the second time. Once popBackStack() has been called the Fragment would be detached from the Activity, so later calls to getActivity() will return null.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `getSupportFragmentManager()` is returning null.  I think your `getActivity()` is returning null based on where you say the crash is happening.

The first time you submit, you will pop the fragment from the stack.  This means the `Fragment` will get detached from the `Activity`.  Thus, `getActivity()` will return null.

To fix this, simply do this:

```
Activity act = getActivity();
if (act == null) {
   // already popped from the stack so no need to do it again.
   return;
}
act.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```

Another way to prevent clicks is to simply disable the button immediately after the first click by calling `setEnabled(false)` or `setClickable(false)`.  You can reenable it once you've confirmed that it's been saved (which wouldn't be a problem in this case case you're leaving instantly anyway).

Comment: Thank you, you and Denley were correct.  I appreciate your thorough response.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking too hard about an easy problem - once the button is clicked, I should remove it and show a loading message instead.  I still don't get why the fragment manager would be null clicking quickly though; popbackstack removes this fragment but the fragmentmanager can still have memory.

Comment: This is a good robust solution. You don't want to be making two network connections for the same operation. You might even end up with duplicate data saved.

Comment: Another way would be to, immediately on click, simply disable the button by calling `setEnable(false)`.  Assuming you don't want to bother the user with anything.